# Android Graphic Lines look jagged

Tags: android, image, layout, graphics, line

I'm manually drawing the graph (see below), and the lines drawn at an angle look jagged and unsmooth.  Is there any way to make them look nicer?

[image]

Comment: This is only a hunch, but the effect you're seeing may have something to do with the way Android renders lines that are very thin. When a 1-pixel-wide line is diagonal, a screen pixel only contains "part" of the line and so it might be rendered darker. What happens if you make the line a couple of pixels wide, instead of just 1?

Comment: Try increasing your paint's `strokeWidth`.

Comment: first one to post that as an answer gets the answer.

Comment: How are you drawing the line? If it's Canvas, I'd suggest trying to smooth the [jaggies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaggies) by setting ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG on your paint (e.g. `Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);`, or `paint.setAntiAlias(true)`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my above comment as an answer:

This is only a hunch, but the effect you're seeing may have something to do with the way Android renders lines that are very thin. When a 1-pixel-wide line is diagonal, a screen pixel only contains "part" of the line and so it might be rendered dimmer. The effect will probably go away if you make the line thicker, since line will "overlap" more of the screen pixels that are on the diagonal.

Answer (score 2):

Did you turn on [anti-aliasing](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=2d_graphics_concepts#Why_Do_My_Graphics_Look_So_Jaggy.3F) in your Paint?

Comment: I didn't, but increasing the line thickness helped. I may try that as well though, always room for improvement.